# How do I write an automake file for CxxTest?

Tags: c++, autoconf, automake, cxxtest

The CxxTest [documentation](http://cxxtest.com/guide.html#_using_makefiles) has an example of a Makefile that generates and runs unit tests. How do I do the same for automake (Makefile.am)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this by creating this `Makefile.am` in a `tests` directory, where all the test code was:

```
check_PROGRAMS = tests

EXTRA_tests_SOURCES  = test_example1.hpp
EXTRA_tests_SOURCES += test_example2.hpp

tests_SOURCES = runner-autogen.cpp

BUILT_SOURCES = runner-autogen.cpp
MAINTAINERCLEANFILES = runner-autogen.cpp

runner-autogen.cpp: $(EXTRA_tests_SOURCES)
    /path/to/cxxtest/bin/cxxtestgen --runner=ErrorPrinter -o $@ $<
```

What this does is compile `runner-autogen.cpp` into the test program (called `tests`) and runs it with `make check`.  If any of the listed `.hpp` files change, it will run `cxxtestgen` to recreate `runner-autogen.cpp`.

Because `runner-autogen.cpp` is listed as a source file, it will be included in the release archive by `make dist`, so the user won't need cxxtest present unless they modify one of the `.hpp` files.